# How can i register a user from laravel user registration table?

Tags: php, laravel-5

When I submit the registration form then the result show below:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'laravel_learn.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate
>   from `users` where `email` = mahfuj.euitsols@gmail.com)

But my user table name is `s_user`, users is not my table name.

**My app/user.php file:**

```
class User extends Model { 
    protected $table = 's_user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id'; 
}
```

How can i register user?

Comment: What is this class **Model** that your **User** model extends?

Comment: What version of laravel do you use? In the new Laravel you shuld extend `Authenticatable` and not `Model`. make sure to use it at the top `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;`

Comment: Nikolay Mihaylov, Thanks